# Stacking Overlapping Events in React FullCalendar Resource Timeline View

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm working on a project where I need to implement a resource timeline view using React and FullCalendar. Specifically, I want to display events stacked on top of each other if their time overlaps. However, despite trying various approaches, I'm unable to achieve this stacking behavior.

Default behavior:
[image]

Expected behavior:
[image]

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import resourceTimelinePlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline";

const events = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Event 1', start: '2024-03-13T08:20:36', end: '2024-03-13T08:23:36', resourceId: "someId" },
  { id: 2, title: 'Event 2', start: '2024-03-13T08:09:36', end: '2024-03-13T10:09:36', resourceId: "someId" }
];

const TimelineView = () => {
  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[timeGridPlugin]}
      initialView="timeGridWeek"
      events={events}
      resources={resources}
    />
  );
};

export default TimelineView;
```

In this setup, events 1 and 2 should stack on top of each other. However, they appear one by one without any stacking.

I've explored options like adjusting eventOverlap and eventDisplay properties in FullCalendar, but I haven't been successful in achieving the desired stacking effect.

Could someone guide me on how to properly stack overlapping events in a resource timeline view using React FullCalendar? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Neither eventOverlap or eventDisplay have the slightest thing to do with stacking, which is clear enough from reading their respective documentation pages. [eventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap) is about constraints when dragging, [eventDisplay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay) is about styles, background colours and highlights. It's unclear why you decided to adjust those settings in relation to this issue, unless it was just random guesswork.

Comment: Your code also has a mistake. Your screenshot clearly shows a Resource Timeline view, and you have loaded the resource-timeline plugin, but then in your settings you've put `initialView="timeGridWeek"`. This doesn't match the screenshot and doesn't  match the plugin you've loaded - without the timeGrid plugin as well, you wouldn't be able to use that view. Try to take more care with the example you provide.

Comment: The reason I mention this is because if you _are_ using a timeGridView, then the [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap) option would be available to you, to control the appearance and stacking/overlapping of events in the display. But in the Timeline view there is no equivalent option. Either you must make your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) with this feature -not an easy task by a long way, or you can request the fullCalendar developers to work on it for you - see [Requesting Features](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)

Comment: I doubt it provides anything for this out of the box; likely, you will have to dig deeper into how the positioning of events works. And you will probably have to implement some sort of "tolerance interval" as well, to decide when you _don't_ want "close" events to overlap like this. (If you had one event from 8:00 to 9:00, and a second one from 8:01 to 8:59, I doubt that would be easily recognizable for the user, if you still just slap them on top of each other, like in that mock-up.)

Comment: CBroe makes a good point...this would be difficult to read for some events, depending on the timing. That's probably a good reason why fullCalendar hasn't implemented what you're asking for.